# AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET MVC4, how are the roles checked?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, filter

I am extending the AuthorizeAttribute to create my own custom AuthorizeUser filter.  I override the:

`AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)` method, to perform my database check manually and return the proper boolean. This works fine but I am looking into examples with Principle and Identity, and I am very confused on when doing something like,

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
```

without overriding the AuthorizeCore method, what is actually happening.

Behind the scenes, where does it get the user's current list of roles to compare to? How is that assigned? I see AuthorizeAttribute has a Roles member, but this is where I am stuck, understanding what it is comparing the passed in values to.

Also, overriding the AuthorizeCore, and grabbing the user roles, and comparing them myself is there any security risks?

Comment: Perhaps understanding the [source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) will help

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks!  I will read it over.